# How to view patches in eclipse workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, rtc

I suspended couple of change sets from the history and created patches from each change set, so that I can submit only those patches for the code review. But I cannot see any of those patches under "Pending Changes" view in eclipse. The source-code control tool that I am using is IBM RTC Jazz. Do I need to add a view or something to show up those patches. please suggest.

**Update:** 
I applied these patches to my project (team --> apply patch), Now I can see all of my patches under "Pending Patches" in "Pending Changes" view. But I don't find an option here to submit only these patches to the code review. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check in the changes into a change set and then they can be submitted for review. You should be able to merge the patches into your workspace by choosing the appropriate option in the context menu by right clicking on  pending patches. Hope this helps.